# Form when submitted to display a result (Firstname) on the thank you page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

Stuck on a thing with PHP, i know it is something simple but am not sure of the correct way of doing it, either by jquery or php.

I have a contact form which when it submits its form, i want the results of some of the fields to display on the results thank you paeg saying:

Thank you for entering **YOURNAME**. Blah blah blah

Is this acheivable with a simple line of php or does it need to called through jquery.

Thanks, only new to php so somethings are still bit confusing

```
   <?php
    define('is_freetrial-celebrity', 1);
    include_once('includes/header.inc.php');
    ?>
    <div role="main" id="main">
        <article id="mainFreetrial" class="greyBlock twoColumnsLayout">
            <header>
                <h1>Get Started</h1>
            </header>
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="/forms_validation/freetrial.php" class="trialForm ajaxForm">
                    <div class="column">

                        <p>
                            <label for="firstNameTrial">First name<sup class="red">*</sup></label><input type="text" id="firstNameTrial" name="firstNameTrial" value="" required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="lastNameTrial">Last name<sup class="red">*</sup></label><input type="text" id="lastNameTrial" name="lastNameTrial" value="" required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="ageTrial">Age</label><input type="text" id="ageTrial" name="ageTrial" value=""/>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label for="celebrityTrial" style="display: block; width: auto; margin-bottom: 5px;">Name the celebrity you would most like to meet, and why?<sup class="red">*</sup></label>
                            <textarea id="celebrityTrial" name="celebrityWhyTrial" style="width: 430px; height: 3em;" required></textarea>
                        </p>

                        <p class="ajaxFormBeforeValid">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit now" class="redButton"/><span class="ajaxFormWait"></span><span class="ajaxFormError error"></span>
                        </p>
                        <div class="ajaxFormValid">
                            <p>
                                Thank you! Your local consultant will contact you soon. 'Like' us while you wait for all the latest VIP offers and promotions!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <small>
                                <sup class="red">*</sup>These are mandatory fields.
                            </small>

                        </p>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('includes/footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

Heres the jquery part

```
/*************************
plugin to manage ajax forms
*************************/
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {

            return this.each(function(){

                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('ajaxForm'),
                    ajaxForm = $('<div />', {
                        text : $this.attr('title')
                    });

                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if ( ! data ) {

                    $(this).data('ajaxForm', {
                        target : $this,
                        ajaxForm : ajaxForm
                    });

                    //get the spinner, the valid box and the error box
                    var mySpinner = $this.find('.ajaxFormWait');
                    var myValid = $this.find('.ajaxFormValid');
                    var myError = $this.find('.ajaxFormError');
                    var myBeforeValid = $this.find('.ajaxFormBeforeValid');

                    myError.hide();
                    mySpinner.hide();

                    //add an event to send the form via AJAX
                    $this.submit(function(){
                        // get all the inputs into an array.
                        var $inputs = $this.find(':input:not([type="submit"], [type="button"])');

                        // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
                        // get an associative array of just the values.
                        var values = {};
                        $inputs.each(function() {
                            if (this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox"){
                                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                                    if(typeof(values[this.name]) === 'undefined'){
                                        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                                    }else{
                                        values[this.name] += ', '+($(this).val());
                                    }
                                }
                            } else
                                values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                        });

                        function defineTheInvalidsFields(fieldsList){
                            for(var i in fieldsList){
                                if(fieldsList[i] == 'closestStudio'){
                                    $this.find('[name="'+fieldsList[i]+'"]').parent().addClass('invalid');
                                }else{
                                    $this.find('[name="'+fieldsList[i]+'"]').addClass('invalid');
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        //send an AJAX request
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $this.attr('action'),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: values,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                mySpinner.show();
                            },
                            success: function(result){
                                mySpinner.hide();
                                $this.find('.invalid').removeClass('invalid');

                                //error management
                                if(typeof(result.valid) === 'undefined'){

                                    if(result.multipleSend){ //if multiple send
                                        myError.html('Your request is already sent.');
                                    }else if(result.required){ //if fields are required
                                        defineTheInvalidsFields(result.required);
                                        myError.html('The fields in red are required.');
                                    }else if(result.format){ //if the forma is incorrect
                                        defineTheInvalidsFields(result.format);
                                        myError.html('The fields in red have invalid content.');
                                    }else if(result.loginInvalid){
                                        myError.html(result.loginInvalid);
                                    }else{
                                        myError.html('An unknown error occured.');
                                    }
                                    myValid.slideUp(300);
                                    myError.slideDown(300);
                                }else if(typeof(result.loginUrl) !== 'undefined'){
                                    window.location.href = result.loginUrl;
                                }else{
                                    if(result.valid || result.valid == 'true'){
                                        if($('#inputFreetrialFitnessFirst').length){
                                            myBeforeValid.slideUp(300);
                                            myError.slideUp(300);
                                            myValid.slideDown(300);
                                        }else{
                                            window.location = '/free-trial-thank-you/';
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        myError.html('There was an error sending your details. Please try again.');
                                        myValid.slideUp(300);
                                        myError.slideDown(300);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    });

                    //special case for the heardAbout
                    $('#heardAbout').change(function(){
                        if($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') == 'Other'){
                            $('#otherHeardAbout').slideDown(300);
                        }else{
                            $('#otherHeardAbout').slideUp(300);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        destroy : function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('ajaxForm');

                // Namespacing FTW
                $(window).unbind('.ajaxForm');
                data.ajaxForm.remove();
                $this.removeData('ajaxForm');
            })
        }
    };

    $.fn.ajaxForm = function( method ) {

        // Method calling logic
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.ajaxForm' );
        }    

    };

})( jQuery );
```

The form gets sent to the other page, is there a way to target a specific div and add the custom message with the name.

```
if(result.valid || result.valid == 'true'){
     if($('#inputFreetrialFitnessFirst').length){
          myBeforeValid.slideUp(300);
          myError.slideUp(300);
          myValid.slideDown(300);
     }else{
          window.location = '/free-trial-thank-you/';
       }
}else{
    myError.html('There was an error sending your details. Please try again.');
    myValid.slideUp(300);
    myError.slideDown(300);
}
```

Comment: So where's your AJAX call? What have you tried?

Comment: @FDL sorry forgot to add that page

Comment: If the form is being submitted by AJAX, just make what is returned be the error or success message and then just display that to the user. What's your actual problem here? Any error messages, etc?

Comment: `this.each(function()`<-- isn't that throwing errors in your console? `this` is a standard JS object here, and has no `each` method AFAIK

Comment: @Mike but how do i dynamically display each persons name each time they submit rather then being a default static thank you message

Comment: @strohy85 `<?php echo "Thank you for submitting my awesome form, $first_name."; ?>` ?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the form/ajax works fine, im just not sure on how to get the persons first name in the thank you message each time the form is submitted.

Comment: @strohy85 what I meant is make the AJAX response be the success or error message and just display that to the user. The server obviously has the person's name because it just got sent with the AJAX request, right?

Comment: @Mike further looking i have realised that this form will go to thank page and not be ajax. Is it possible to call the field on the separate page.

Comment: On success u want to redirect it to another page with the information passed to the other page right?

Comment: @madi yes. on the other page, i want it to have the message saying thank you with the persons name that had field out the form

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of is using session to store the information.

1. At freetrial.php store the form information in session like this:

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['firtNameTrial'] = $_GET['firstNameTrial'];
   ```
2. On ajax success, redirect the page to the thank you page using javascript windows.location.replace:

   ```
     // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
     window.location.replace("http://yourwebpageaddress.com/thankyou.php");
   ```
3. Get the session on the thank you page. If you don't know, you may look at this example: [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for session example

Answer (score 0):

if You wand to fetch specific element div via ajax call You can do like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'page.html',
success: function(data) {
    item=$(data).filter('#specific_element');
    $(selector).html(item); 
 }
});
```

If You wand to redirect to other page using

```
window.location = '/free-trial-thank-you/';
```

and then show data on a different page You should pass needet parameters like

```
 window.location = '/free-trial-thank-you/page.php?name1=Daniel&name2=Pablo;
```

and on different site show parameters using _GET or _POST for example:
`echo $_GET['name1'] or echo $_POST['name1']` if You use PSOT method in Your Ajax request